# Call to API is not returning response in Android but working fine in Browser

Tags: android, angularjs, cordova, ionic-framework

I'm building a Cordova Ionic application which fetches JSON response on button click and display it. It's working fine in browser but it's not displaying anything in android.

```
angular.module('starter', ['ionic'])

.config(function($ionicConfigProvider) {
  $ionicConfigProvider.navBar.alignTitle('center');  //align title in center
})

.controller('ControllerOne',[ '$scope', 'freshlyPressed', Ctrl])

.service('freshlyPressed', ['$http','$log', freshlyPressed]);

function Ctrl($scope, freshlyPressed){

  $scope.refreshClicked = function(){
    freshlyPressed.getBlogs($scope);
  }
};

function freshlyPressed($http,$log){
  this.getBlogs = function($scope){
    $http.jsonp("https://public-api.wordpress.com/rest/v1.1/freshly-pressed?callback=JSON_CALLBACK")
    .success(function(result, posts){
      $scope.posts = result.posts;
    });
  };
};
```

How would I know if any exception occurred while testing the app in android?

[Edit] I'm new to Android & Cordova.

Answer (score 1):

The only way you can find out if something goes wrong is if you add a `.error` function after the `.success` function, otherwise errors will not be caught.

Here is a code example for your current situation:

```
function freshlyPressed($http,$log){
  this.getBlogs = function($scope){
    $http.jsonp("https://public-api.wordpress.com/rest/v1.1/freshly-pressed?callback=JSON_CALLBACK")
    .success(function(result, posts){
      $scope.posts = result.posts;
    })
    .error(function(error){
      console.log(error);
    });
  };
};
```

Although, I would highly recommend you switch to the `.then()` function, as `.error` and `.success` have been deprecated as described [here](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/service/$http).

Comment: It's working fine in browser. I think there is no issue with code. Internet permission is also added. Still not working in android.

Answer (score 0):

You can debug your android apps with Chrome using DevTool.

To enable Remote Debugging  follow these  [Remote Debugging Devices Documetation](https://developers.google.com/web/tools/chrome-devtools/debug/remote-debugging/remote-debugging?hl=en)
 .

To use it follow [Chrome Inspector (Ionic Docs)](http://docs.ionic.io/docs/chrome-inspector).

Hope this may help you.